# Error when compiling with clang and threading

Tags: c++, multithreading, gcc, clang

```
$ clang --std=c++0x -O1 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g ./prog.cpp 
In file included from ./prog.cpp:41:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/thread:37:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/chrono:666:7: error: static_assert expression is not an integral constant expression
      static_assert(system_clock::duration::min()
      ^             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
$
```

I have gcc 4.8 installed, but it's using 4.6libs . I believe if it used 4.8 this would not happen (read that somewhere when I first had the issue).

I also have 4.6 installed but I can't remove that without my system flipping out. elementaryOS.

Compiling the code below triggers this bug (yes, I know, I didn't join. Just an example.)

```
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

void func(int a);
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    thread(func, 5);    
    return 0;
}
void func(int a){
    a++;
}
```

Comment: You might need to pass additional `-I`  flags to your compiler

Comment: What does clang have to do with this? (the title doesn't seem to match the question content at *all* ? Also, a trivial source text including `#include`'s and minimal coded `main()` to reproduce this should be posted along with the error (thanks for posting that, btw).

Comment: Any source that contains threading should trigger this. I'll try to write one up.

Comment: I've added a source file that gives me the exact same bug when I compile using that clang command.

Comment: Did you try `clang++ -std=c++0x -O1 -fno-omit-frame-pointer ...` ? (note the ++ and the single `-` in front of the `std=` switch). With your posted sample, this flies on my Mac (clang 3.4).

Comment: No. I believe the problem is that it is using the path /usr/include/c++/4.6/thread when it should be using 4.8.

Comment: @user3816764 I concur you're likely correct. The verbose output on my rig pulls in clang-only paths and libs. Your setup is anomalistic in comparison. I think Basile is on to something in the first comment in this thread.

Comment: Yes, I just don't know what to pass in order to specific the path properly. I want it to use the libc++ from 4.8.